# I'm not a pretty girl

Tags: riddle

> Whatever I wear, it will always be a good combo.
>   I'm so super hot.
>
> I'm very good at creating a romantic setting.
>   Please don't leave me alone.
>
> Your parents don't wan't us to play together.
>   Please don't touch me.

It's not a pretty girl.
So what is it?

Comment: Title: Ani DiFranco?

Comment: Dammit. Ignoring the title, I first thought it was a pretty girl...

Comment: breasts got close, but nope

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are a

> MATCH

Whatever I wear, it will always be a good combo.

> the outfit is a match

I'm so super hot.

> Literally so.

I'm very good at creating a romantic setting.

> Lighting Candles

Please don't leave me alone.

> A lone item isn't a part of a Match

Your parents don't wan't us to play together.

> Don't play with matches!

Please don't touch me.

> Not sure about this one.

Comment: Don't touch an activated [blank] otherwise you will get injury.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't leave a [blank] alone; otherwise, you could [blank] down your [blank].

Answer (score 33):

The answer is:

> Fire (credit to @GarethMcCaughan who got this answer first)

What ever I wear, it will always be a good combo.

> "Wear" can also mean to use up or gradually damage. Fire destroys things and burns up fuel.
>
>  Fire requires a "combo" of heat, fuel and oxygen in order to burn. So whatever it "wears" or destroys has to be a flammable source of fuel.

I'm so super hot.

> Obviously, fire is hot. Literally.

I'm very good at creating a romantic setting.

> Candlelight is considered romantic, as are controlled fires such as campfires.

Please don't leave me alone.

> You should never leave a fire unattended.

Your parents don't wan't us to play together.

> Parents instill into children not to play with fire.

Please don't touch me.

> Unless you want to get burned!

Comment: Combo could also be short for rot13(pbzohfgvba)?

Comment: @Cain no? Never; it's always just short for combination in some context or other.

Answer (score 10):

I expect you are

> either *a candle*, or *fire* more generally

but I don't really understand the first line. (The rest, I take it, are obvious given the answer I am proposing.)

Comment: What ever I wear, it will always be a good combo > N pnaqyr ubyqre vf nyjnlf n tbbq pbzovangvba jvgu n pnaqyr

Comment: Maybe, but that's hardly "*whatever* I wear", is it?

Answer (score 8):

I definitely think the other answers are more fitting, but the first thing to come to mind to me was

> A rose

Whatever I wear, it will always be a good combo.
I'm so super hot.

> Roses look good in practically every bouquet. Traditionally, they are red- a warm/"hot" color.

I'm very good at creating a romantic setting.
Please don't leave me alone.

> Roses are pretty much the most generic romantic flower ever. However, you're not going to buy a bush: you're going to buy a pre-cut bouquet. In order to keep the flowers alive for a while you'll have to tend to them (cut off the bottom of the stems, give it that miracle food powder, water in the vase, etc.)

Your parents don't wan't us to play together.
Please don't touch me.

> We had a rosebush when I was young. I grabbed it and got thorns in my hand. Don't play with roses, kids- they've got protection!

Answer (score 3):

I would go with a

> lightbulb

Whatever I wear, it will always be a good combo.

> every lamp shade, however bad, someone will like

I'm so super hot.

> especially the iridescent ones

I'm very good at creating a romantic setting.

> lighting is always important

Please don't leave me alone.

> it wastes energy.

Your parents don't wan't us to play together.

> broken glass sounds like a bad thing

Please don't touch me.

> grease on the glass tends to reduce a bulbs life.

Answer (score 0):

Well, already answers are provided, but here is my take

> It could be a mannequin

As,
Whatever I wear, it will always be a good combo.
I'm so super hot.

> Usually mannequins, if provided with all body parts - are super hot, with any kind of dress.

I'm very good at creating a romantic setting.
Please don't leave me alone.

> If pairs of mannequins ( of opposite genders) are taken, they can be arranged for romantic setting(s).Not sure of the part- "..don't leave me alone."

Your parents don't wan't us to play together.
Please don't touch me.

> As children, we may have a tendency to play with toys, but these are life-size and are usually placed in shops, for which parents do Not allow us to play with them. And hence - do not touch.

It's not a pretty girl.
So what is it?

> In a certain angle, they are not pretty. It is a mannequin.

Comment: Could you explain how it fits all the lines?  I'm not seeing how it works for some.

Answer (score -1):

Obviously, you're going for something flame related. My sigoth, however, immediately hit on a perfectly valid alternative answer.

> A bad *boy*.

Whatever I wear, it will always be a good combo.

> Gunmetal gray eyes go with everything.

I'm so super hot.

> Mwawr.

I'm very good at creating a romantic setting.

> Yes, indeed.

Please don't leave me alone.

> The sensitive side I can only share with you...

Your parents don't wan't us to play together.

> Yes, I know you love them but they can be such bigots/hypocrites sometimes...

Please don't touch me.

> I don't know what I want/I might lose control...

Answer (score -2):

Out of the box answer...

You are

> [Yuno Gasai](http://futurediary.wikia.com/wiki/Yuno_Gasai), from Mirai Nikki.

Whatever I wear, it will always be a good combo.

> Be it axes, knives or guns, that yandere can put in a combo.

I'm so super hot.

> Because Yandere is sexy.

I'm very good at creating a romantic setting.

> Yuuu-ki...

Please don't leave me alone.

> Don't ignore Yuno. You might end up drugged and bound in your undies.

Your parents don't wan't us to play together.

> They don't even want you to meet her. Something about reduced life expectancy.

Please don't touch me.

> You don't know how she will react. You might get stabbed in all that excitement.

I'm not a pretty girl

> Yuno may be cool, sexy, enticing. But a psychopath is not a "pretty girl".

Comment: Well then. Now I've seen everything.

Comment: Nah, she's pretty.